# Is volley library better or native HTTPClient for exchanging data with server?

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I am developing an app which exchange lot of data with server by making HTTP calls.Mostly data is text.So which approach should i follow for exchanging the data with server.I want to send & get data from server using POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For below Ginger Bread, Volley uses HttpClient it self and for later version HttpURLConnection. So basically it is wrapper for these.

It offers some ease of use ie.

cancel pending calls,

Async in nature, response on UI thread,

Easy image downloading and cache/storing (NetworkImageView),

Rest based calls (JSON handling),

Retrying failed requests and customizing request Timeout,

which makes it quite easy to use and plate full of boiler-plate facilities.

A simple comparison through a presentation [here](https://prezi.com/lanlt2peo8vf/android-networking-without-the-pain/)

Comment: can i send send param with each http request in volley as we do with httpclient for both Get & Post request?

Comment: @techguy: yes you can, its way too basic to be not present in any library.

Comment: can you provide me some reference for doing this thing?

Comment: Search "Volley post request" on google and you'll get your ans in first three posts

Comment: but i don't wan to make json request only a simple string request

Answer (score 0):

Volley is better than HTTP calls because it handles all errors automatically and even a faster tool for making web service requests.
I am using this from last six months and realized that its much better tool than usual HttpClient.

Comment: There are also policies available to implement like retry policy etc.
And also have features to manage request ques .

Comment: can i send send param with each http request in volley as we do with httpclient for both Get & Post request?